# ESLint not throwing any errors from npm command

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint, lint

***Below is the configuration setup for `eslint`. Trying to define a basic `eslint` rule to define `const` instead of `let` if its an array or object***

```
"scripts": {
  "lint": "eslint src/**/*.js --fix"
}
```

**.eslintrc**

```
"rules": {
    "strict": [2, "never"],
    "prefer-const": 2
}
```

> vscode referring to .eslintrc file for the rule defined on
>   prefer-const and throwing error in ide as below which is perfectly
>   fine

[image]

> But npm run lint is not giving any error on the same nor fixing the code

[image]

Attaching the folder structure below where `eslintrc` is located
[image]
What is missing in my script?

Comment: Maybe, it's fixing it for you? Since you have `--fix` flag?

Comment: It’s not even fixing not giving any errors from command line

Comment: And the .eslintrc file is in the folder from where you're running the command?

Comment: Yes it is in root project folder

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of your folder structure?

Comment: @ManishGharat - updated the question along with screenshot. FYI i am using mac.

Answer (score 0):

Your config file name should be `.eslintrc.json`.

Here's the reference documentation you can check: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring

Also attaching a link to deprecation notice for .eslintrc file without extension: https://dev.to/ohbarye/eslintrc-without-file-extension-is-deprecated-3ngg

Try changing your config file name and it should work.